# How to run a command inside a virtualenv using systemd

Tags: systemd, python, python3, virtualenv

I believe this should be simple but I can't get it to work properly.

These are the commands I can run on command line:

```
cd /home/debian/ap

# Start a virtualenv
source venv-ap/bin/activate

# This needs to happen inside the virtualenv and takes ~20 seconds
crossbar start

# Outside the virtualenv, perhaps in a different command line window
python3 /home/debian/myscript.py
```

These commands have to be done in this order. Due to the virtualenv, the non-executable for crossbar, and the separate python script afterwards, I haven't been able to figure out the best way to get this to work. My current work-in-progress:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start CB
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=debian
ExecStartPre=source /home/debian/ap/venv-ap/bin/activate
ExecStart=cd /home/debian/ap/ && crossbar start
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Could you solve it yet? If so, how?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This doesn't work because `source` is a shell command, so systemd's `ExecStart=` or `ExecStartPre=` won't understand them directly... (BTW, the same is true for `cd` and the `&&`.)

You *could* achieve that by running a shell explicitly and running all your commands together there:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'cd /home/debian/ap/ && source venv-ap/bin/activate && crossbar start'
```

But a better approach is, instead of sourcing the "activate" script, to use the `python` executable in the `bin/` of your virtualenv directly.

If you look at virtualenv's [usage document](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#usage), you'll notice it says:

> `ENV/bin` is created, where executables live - noticeably a new **python**. Thus running a script with `#! /path/to/ENV/bin/python` would run that script under this virtualenv’s python.

In other words, assuming `crossbar` is the Python script you want to run that requires the `venv-ap` virtualenv, simply begin `crossbar` with:

```
#!/home/debian/ap/venv-ap/bin/python
```

And it will automatically use the virtualenv whenever invoked.

Also possible, invoking the Python interpreter from the virtualenv directly, with:

```
ExecStart=/home/debian/ap/venv-ap/bin/python /path/to/crossbar start
```

(Also, regarding running in a specific directory, setting `WorkingDirectory=/home/debian/ap` is better than using a `cd` command. You don't need a shell that way, and systemd can do better error handling for you.)

Comment: But, the `.venv/bin/activate` script does more than setting the interpreter. E.g. installing packages does not work. `/path/to(venv/python -m pip install django" does not what it should.

Comment: @nerdoc I haven't tested it myself... The [venv docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#module-venv) call out usage without activating explicitly: *"You don’t specifically need to activate an environment; activation just prepends the virtual environment’s binary directory to your path, so that “python” invokes the virtual environment’s Python interpreter and you can run installed scripts without having to use their full path. However, all scripts installed in a virtual environment should be runnable without activating it, and run with the virtual environment’s Python automatically."*

Comment: Activate appears to only do a few things: 1) define `deactivate` 2) adds venv dir to PATH 3) defines a couple of other envvars (for scripting purposes).  You get your venv dirs in your `sys.path` from the venved python executable directly however.  @nerdoc your command works for me from CLI.   If there is a problem from systemd, sometimes you have to mimic `activate` by adding venv path via `Environment` becuase some python modules with do things like `subprocess.Popen` to spawn processes from venvs `bin`. Not 100% sure that's your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I want to iterate on @filbranden's answer second part

> But a better approach is, instead of sourcing the "activate" script, to use the python executable in the bin/ of your virtualenv directly.
>
> If you look at virtualenv's usage document, you'll notice it says:
>
> > ENV/bin is created, where executables live - noticeably a new python. Thus running a script with #! /path/to/ENV/bin/python would run that script under this virtualenv’s python.

Don't run stuff in venv without activating it! To be fair, the documentation **is** also misleading. Activating the venv makes you able to separate the working directory from the python (and venv-ed packages') path which **is a must** quite often: you don't want to run/place something in the venv bin directly, but you installed some script's dependencies to it.

Consider the following (which I bet is one of the most common) scenario:

- you need to run a script from a git repo with but it has its dependencies incompatible with your python packages
- you created a virtualenv and pip installed the dependencies there
- you cloned the repo somewhere, but the script doesn't lies in venv's bin.

If you even want to work on the app from the git repo, you want its folder to be pristine, except your meaningful code modifications. You wouldn't want to change shebang. You can put the whole venv into a subdir in the cloned repo and gitignore it to keep everything organized, but then:

- you would set the systemd working dir to the cloned folder
- you would run with script with the subfolder's python full path
- script will not find the pip-ed deps, as they are not in the working folder, neither in the path
  The problem remains if you reverse the folder hierarchy (clone the repo to the venv's subfolder).

Also, maybe you don't want to run python directly, but e.g.: gunicorn, and you placed the webapp to `/srv` while the venv is in `/var/lib`.

**Not activating a venv is not a good habit to pick up**, I wonder how that moronic paragraph made it into the official venv docs. Yeah, activating it is not needed in some cases *except in quite a lot of real-world scenarios!* - I argue.

`ExecStartPre` won't work for sourcing venv anyway, as that is executed in a different shell than `ExecStart`'s command, so environment variables won't be right in the latter.

I'd advise setting the venv PATH with `Environment`

Comment: Maybe there is a more specific problem you're alluding to?  venvs are just syntactic sugar around common commands.  If a user runs everything in `activate` then they didn't technically `activate` but its the same state. Maybe you're saying something is missing by just pointing to the venv python?  Pip WILL find the dependencies. The venved python has mechanics to see pip-ed dep. Try yourself: `full_path_venv_python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'` -- site-packages in sys.path ready to import piped deps.