# Alter environment variables within a shell script runned by systemd

Tags: shell-script, systemd, python, environment-variables

I would like to run a script as a systemd service, the script is a bash wrapper script that runs a python script. The python script needs to run in a specific conda environment.

I have tried setting the conda environment in the bash script just before running the python command, I get errors of unknown packaged names because the environments have not been altered by `conda activate`.

What I found funny is that I have also `source ~/.bashrc` and output the content of `$PATH` in a log file to check if `$PATH` has been altered in the script and the answer is no...

*script.sh*

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bashrc
conda activate my_env
echo "$PATH" >> ~/log
python3 ~/my_python_script.py
```

*test.service* (in *~/.config/systemd/user*

```bsh
[Unit]
Description=Testing

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/path/to/script.sh
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a command inside a virtualenv using systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409609/how-to-run-a-command-inside-a-virtualenv-using-systemd)

Comment: I hasd other environments to pass as well, so even though it seems that I was asking specificly for conda, the question was about environments in general. Sorry for not having been clear enough.